# why is php bccomp equal？

Tags: php, bcmath

php version 5.4.33
php.ini: bcmath.scale = 0 (also tried bcmath.scale = PHP_INI_ALL)

problem:

php5433 -r "echo bccomp(0.00000001, 0, 9);"
print 0

php5433 -r "echo bccomp(1.00000001, 1, 9);"
print 1

why? Anyone can help?

Comment: please provide more information, like what are you trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

it's because [`bccomp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bccomp.php) first 2 arguments are meant to be strings. as you can see [here](http://www.tehplayground.com/#cSdpsJi8U) when they are strings it works as expected. why is this? i'm not sure but it probably has something to with why `echo 0.00000001;` outputs 1.0E-8 (the [Scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)) while `echo 1.00000001;` outputs 1.00000001 ([example](http://www.tehplayground.com/#ydQA7ZWfn))

[`bcmath.scale = 0`](http://php.net/manual/en/bc.configuration.php#ini.bcmath.scale) only sets the default scale value when it's not supplied like [`bcscale`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcscale.php)

> Sets the default scale parameter for all subsequent calls to bc math functions that do not explicitly specify a scale parameter.